# custom user meta query

Tags: customization, query, user-meta

I've been trying to get this query to work but it keeps failing to return any rows

```
SELECT a.ID 
  FROM wp_users a, wp_usermeta b 
WHERE b.user_id=a.ID 
AND (
  (b.meta_key='firstname-groom' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Darren') 
  OR (b.meta_key='firstname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Someone') 
  OR (b.meta_key='lastname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Cool')
) 
AND (b.meta_key='weddingdate' AND b.meta_value='12/14/2014') 
GROUP BY a.ID
```

The query return rows if I remove this part `AND (b.meta_key='weddingdate' AND b.meta_value='12/14/2014')`
but I need to be able to make it work with that requirement (weddingdate=12/14/2014)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i figured it out now using join

```
SELECT a.ID FROM wp_users a INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b ON b.user_id = a.ID AND 
(
( b.meta_key = 'firstname-groom' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Darren' )
OR ( b.meta_key = 'firstname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Someone' )
OR ( b.meta_key = 'lastname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Cool' )
)
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta c ON c.user_id = a.ID AND 
( c.meta_key = 'weddingdate' AND c.meta_value = '12/14/2014' )
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SQL` does not trigger an error, so you do not have data in your database that matches all of the criteria. As written, you'd need one or more of these:

```
(b.meta_key='firstname-groom' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Darren') 
OR (b.meta_key='firstname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Someone') 
OR (b.meta_key='lastname-bride' AND b.meta_value LIKE 'Cool')
```

And this:

```
AND (b.meta_key='weddingdate' AND b.meta_value='12/14/2014')
```

To match for this to return results. However, if you look carefully, that condition is never going to occur because it would require that `b.meta_key` be both `weddingdate` and one of `firstname-groom`, `firstname-bride`, `lastname-bride` at the same time, which  will never happen. You will need to `JOIN` the tables multiple times once for the names and once for the date. (It looks like you worked that out already in a comment, so I won't write the `SQL`.)

I would make another comment though.

1. Saving a date like `12/14/2014` is a bad idea. [There is very little
   rational sorting you can do with that date format](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78046/order-by-custom-field-date/78048#78048) and extracting
   month, day, or year data is not going to be especially efficient or
   reliable as none of `MySQL`'s date functions will work.

I would suggest a [user query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) but looking at your `SQL` I think the logic is too complicated for that class.

Comment: yea i dont need any rational sorting for the date it needs to be exact and will always be in that format (from jqueryui-datepicker) so a string is fine for this particular case

Comment: But converting the date is simple enough and much more future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m1.`user_id` as `ID`, m1.p1, m2.p2, m3.p3, m4.p4 
        FROM 
            (SELECT `user_id`, `meta_value` as p1 FROM `wp_usermeta`
                WHERE (`meta_key` = 'firstname-groom' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'Darren') 
            GROUP BY `user_id`) m1,
            (SELECT `user_id`, `meta_value` as p2 FROM `wp_usermeta`
                WHERE (`meta_key` = 'firstname-bride' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'Someone') 
            GROUP BY `user_id`) m2,
            (SELECT `user_id`, `meta_value` as p3 FROM `wp_usermeta`
                WHERE (`meta_key` = 'lastname-bride' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'Cool') 
            GROUP BY `user_id`) m3,
            (SELECT `user_id`, `meta_value` as p4 FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE (`meta_key` = 'weddingdate' AND `meta_value` = '12/14/2014' )
            GROUP BY `user_id`) m4
        WHERE
            m1.`user_id` = m2.`user_id` AND m1.`user_id` = m3.`user_id` AND m1.`user_id` = m4.`user_id`
```

If necessary, where it was ready function generating such queries. The function returns an array of user IDs

Comment: `EXPLAIN` gives "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const table..."

Comment: Do not quite understand what you mean. Use similar in my project. You can replace the group m1 adding a parameter query OR. Plus, you can use CAST or CONVERT to convert values ​​on the fly.

Comment: Put the keyword `EXPLAIN` in front of the query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: It all depends on the severity of queries...

Comment: No idea what that means but MySQL thinks that the `WHERE` clause will always be false. I get the same message with your code as-is, and when I substitute values that should be valid for my database. The problem, I think, is that you require `m1.`user_id` = m2.`user_id` which requires someone to have two first names. Your query is a very complicated construction-- overly complicated I'd say-- but it looks like the equivalent of an `AND` query for all of the fields. That is not what the OP wants.