# query_posts with sorting on a custom datestamp

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, query-posts, sort, order

I have a custom meta field that I want to use to sort with `query_posts` but its not ordering my posts properly since it is a datestamp (i.e. 04/21/2014) and its treating it like a normal text string.

I thought about converting the field using `strtotime` but that doesn't work.

```
$args = array(
  'meta_key'      => strtotime('pexpires'),
  'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
  'order'         => 'desc',
  'post_type'     => 'post',
  'showposts'     => '60',
);
$query = query_posts($args);
```

Comment: I am fairly sure this a duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/78046/21376

Comment: You should take a look at `'meta_key' => strtotime('pexpires')`. `strtotime` will simply return `false`, as no valid date string is passed. A further look in the WP codex might help a well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters